# Validating nested objects with Joi

Tags: node.js, api, hapi.js, joi

How to validate this object using joi? Im using Joi with Hapi api.

```
    {
    "email":"rambo@gmail.com",
    "password":"abc123",
    "active":"",
    "details": {
        "firstName": "Rambo",
        "lastName": "Comando",
        "phoneNumber": "5554446655",
        "billing":{
            "firstName": "",
            "lastName": "",
            "phoneNumber": "",
            "address": "",
            "adress2": "",
            "postalCode": "",
            "city": "",
            "state": "",
            "country": "",
            "stripeId": ""
        }
     }
  }
```

I tried doing like this, but it is not working. What is the correct way of doing this?

```
payload: {
        email: Joi.string().email().required(),
        password: Joi.string().alphanum().min(8).max(30).required(),
        active: Joi.boolean(),
        details: Joi.object().keys({
            firstName: Joi.string().max(50),
            lastName: Joi.string().max(50),
            phoneNumber: Joi.number().integer().min(10).max(11),
            billing : Joi.object().keys({
                firstName: Joi.string().max(50),
                lastName: Joi.string().max(50),
                phoneNumber: Joi.string().integer().min(10).max(11),
                address: Joi.string().alphanum(),
                adress2: Joi.string().alphanum(),
                postalCode: Joi.string().alphanum(),
                city: Joi.string(),
                state: Joi.string(),
                country: Joi.string(),
                stripeId: Joi.string().alphanum()
            })
        })
    }
```

Im not sure where im missing things up.

Comment: Could you please specify what you mean by "not working"?

Comment: @KidBinary hey, well it simply wont run my node.js app. the problem is in this validation since i have many others but not nested objects like this one.

Comment: It throws Node.js exception, Joi validation error or simply ignoring the payload you're trying to validate with it?

Comment: @KidBinary i fixed the phoNumber but still not working.  Im using it on my Hapi router.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an error in your code, at this line:

```
phoneNumber: Joi.string().integer().min(10).max(11),
```

The Node.js throws exception because of it:

> TypeError: Joi.integer is not a function

If you change that to either `string()` or `number()` everything will work as it should:

```
phoneNumber: Joi.number().min(10).max(11),
```

It's quite obvious so I'm just wondering, how you've missed it? Everything else with your Joi schema seems alright.

Comment: Glad to help : )